# TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() > int()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python3, and am getting the following error trying to read earthquake data from last day!!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Z:\Python learning\Up and run\Exercise Files\Ch5\jsondata_finished.py", line 54, in <module>
    main()
  File "Z:\Python learning\Up and run\Exercise Files\Ch5\jsondata_finished.py", line 49, in main
    printResults(data)
  File "Z:\Python learning\Up and run\Exercise Files\Ch5\jsondata_finished.py", line 33, in printResults
    if (feltReports != None) & (feltReports > 0):
TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() > int()
```

I am unable to identify the error. Here is my CODE:

```
import urllib.request
import json

def printResults(data):
  # Use the json module to load the string data into a dictionary
  theJSON = json.loads(data.decode())

  # now we can access the contents of the JSON like any other Python object
  if "title" in theJSON["metadata"]:
    print (theJSON["metadata"]["title"])

  # output the number of events, plus the magnitude and each event name  
  count = theJSON["metadata"]["count"];
  print (str(count) + " events recorded")

  # for each event, print the place where it occurred
  for i in theJSON["features"]:
    print (i["properties"]["place"])

  # print the events that only have a magnitude greater than 4
  # for i in theJSON["features"]:
    # if i["properties"]["mag"] >= 4.0:
      # print "%2.1f" % i["properties"]["mag"], i["properties"]["place"]

  # print only the events where at least 1 person reported feeling something
  print ("Events that were felt:")
  for i in theJSON["features"]:
    feltReports = i["properties"]["felt"]
    if (feltReports != None) & (feltReports > 0):
        print ("%2.1f" % i["properties"]["mag"], i["properties"]["place"], " reported " + str(feltReports) + " times")


def main():
  # define a variable to hold the source URL
  # In this case we'll use the free data feed from the USGS
  # This feed lists all earthquakes for the last day larger than Mag 2.5
  urlData = "http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_day.geojson"

  # Open the URL and read the data
  webUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(urlData)
  print (webUrl.getcode())
  if (webUrl.getcode() == 200):
    data = webUrl.read()
    # print out our customized results
    printResults(data)
  else:
    print ("Received an error from server, cannot retrieve results " + str(webUrl.getcode()))

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Please help! I have tried to do a few things over by looking at the solutions of other users, but still i was getting the same error over and over again.

Comment: `&` is a bitwise operator, you need to use `and`.

Comment: Thank you. Solved my problem!

Can you post a link about how i can counter such errors in the future by myself.

Answer (score 1):

Use `and` instead of `&`. Also, use `is not None` to check if object is not `None` instead of `!= None`